# wordpress sub-directory sites on a sub-domain?

Tags: directory, subdomains, domain-mapping, iis

I have a large site at www.example.com this is a .net site

I want to use WP multisite installed at word.example.com this would point to the WP root install directory but on a different server than the root of the domain www.example.com

then all new sub-sites in the WP multisite would be e.g. word.example.com/site1 word.example.com/site2

is this possible?  does anyone have any info they can point me to? I have been searching but not yet seen this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to create a  multi install on a sub directory, this has no connection with the root domain? That is possible. http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue. For all hosting intents and purposes `word.example.com` would be completely different domain to `www.example.com`. Just point it to WP server (using your hosting or domain registrar, depending on your domain setup) and business as usual from there.